# Delete polygons that have one or more side parts in common

Tags: python, polygon, geojson, shapely, linestring

I am trying to solve a particular case of comparison of polygons to others. I have **five** polygons distributed as in the figure below. The black polygon is the one with the largest area.

There may be other similar cases, **the main rule is to remove the smallest polygons among all those that have one or more side portions in common**.

The data for this case are in a GeoJson file as follows:

```py
{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[
    {"type":"Feature","properties":{"id":1},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[3.4545135498046875,45.533288879467456],[3.4960556030273433,45.533288879467456],[3.4960556030273433,45.57055337226086],[3.4545135498046875,45.57055337226086],[3.4545135498046875,45.533288879467456]]]}},
    {"type":"Feature","properties":{"id":2},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[3.4545135498046875,45.52917023833511],[3.4960556030273433,45.52917023833511],[3.4960556030273433,45.53891018749409],[3.4545135498046875,45.53891018749409],[3.4545135498046875,45.52917023833511]]]}},
    {"type":"Feature","properties":{"id":3},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[3.4845542907714844,45.5298015824607],[3.5159683227539062,45.5298015824607],[3.5159683227539062,45.543388795387294],[3.4845542907714844,45.543388795387294],[3.4845542907714844,45.5298015824607]]]}},
    {"type":"Feature","properties":{"id":4},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[3.465328216552734,45.542667432984864],[3.4735679626464844,45.542667432984864],[3.4735679626464844,45.5478369923404],[3.465328216552734,45.5478369923404],[3.465328216552734,45.542667432984864]]]}},
    {"type":"Feature","properties":{"id":5},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[3.4545138850808144,45.56799974017372],[3.4588050842285156,45.56799974017372],[3.4588050842285156,45.57055290285386],[3.4545138850808144,45.57055290285386],[3.4545138850808144,45.56799974017372]]]}}]}
```

Is there a solution to delete **only** the two **blue** polygons?

By transforming the Polygons into LineString one could look if a Linestring is a portion of another Linestring ? But I don't see how to do it. Or maybe looking to see if the LineString of the black and blue polygons have more than two points in common ? But how do you convert a LineString into more than two points?

[image]

Comment: What is the rule that makes the blue polygons the ones to be deleted? Please make sure your question clearly states that.

Comment: And can you provide example data? It should be possible to make a test case that nicely fits into the question so people can use real data.

Comment: So it seem manually selecting these polygons is not an option? Why? Do you have a lot of similar cases? There are a lot of things unclear with your question. Like this, it's not only impossible to help, but also the question risks to je closed. To avoid this unpleasant experience, edit it and clearly describe what you have.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I put data and explanations. Yes I have similar cases in a same geojson file.

Comment: Still not clear: based on what criteria should two polygons be deleted? As of now, the color (blue) is the only indication you give. For anyone reading your question, it is does not become clear what makes the blue polygons different from the other ones. Or are you asking about how to delete polygons with a certain color (blue)?

Comment: @Babel I updated by saying the main rule. Is there still any information missing?

Comment: Now it seems to be clear. So all polygons should be deleted that at least in part share a side with the biggest one, right?

Comment: An idea: 1) calculate area for all polygons, get the polygon with the largest area. 2) Check if at least one (or 2?) vertices of the other polygons lie on the boundary of the polygon with the largest area.

Comment: I tried but the subtlety is that the coordinates are not exactly the same even if we see that the sides of two figures overlap. This is the case for example between polygon 1 and 5.

Answer (score 0):

1. Calculate the area of the polygons and get the largest one. For this, create a new layer with its boundary. Use [`Geometry by expression`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html?#geometry-by-expression) for seelcted symbols only with this expression: `boundary ($geometry)`.
2. Select all other polygons and create a new layer that represents a (very) tiny buffer around the boundary. The buffer size should be just large enough so that it overlaps with the line from step 1 for the polygons you want to delete. Use again [`Geometry by expression`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html?#geometry-by-expression) for seelcted symbols only with this expression: `buffer (boundary ($geometry),[distance])` and replace `[distance]` by the distance value that fits your data.

*Steps 3 and 4 are intermediate steps to make you understand how it works. YOu could just skip them and proceed to step 5 immediately.*

3. Now get the intersection of the buffer-layer from step 2 with the boundary-layer from step 1 (see next step how). You get the blue geometries:
   [image]
4. As we want to get rid of the points where two lines simply crosss, we only retain lines that are longer than a ceratin threshold (slightly larger than the size of the buffer). For this, use the following expression, replacing `[threshold]` with a value that fits your data:

   ```
    length (
        intersection (
            $geometry, 
            geometry (
                get_feature_by_id (
                    'boundary',
                    1
                )
            )
        )
    )>[threshold],
    $geometry, 
    '')
   ```

You'll get the blue (very small)  polygons:
[image]

5. Now, instead of creating the blue geometries, on the buffer layer create a new feild with field calculator to create a field called `select` where instead of the geometry, you create a value 1 where you before had the geometry and 0 in all other cases. Use this expression (based on the one above) - again, set an appropriate value for `[threshold]`:

   ```
    length (
        intersection (
            $geometry, 
            geometry (
                get_feature_by_id (
                    'boundary',
                    1
                )
            )
        )
    )>[threshold],
    1, 
    0)
   ```
6. Run `Join attributes by position` - see screenshot how - to get the attribute from step 5 to a copy of the initial polygon layer.
   [image]
7. In the resulting layer, use select by expression with `select=1` and de-select the largest polygon. The remaining two are the polygons you want to delete:

[image]

Comment: Very interesting, but I was thinking more of an idea or solution in python without going through qgis.

Comment: You can adapt the principles of the solution with Python. However, next time you ask a question, clearly state state from the beginning as detailed as possible what defines your task, what the result should look like and what tools you want to focus on. This helps finding the solutions you're looking for. Others can't intuitively guess what you want.

Comment: Yes I can maybe adapt to python, thanks for the answer, note that I had put the `python` tag on the question.